# Clarification of this narration/hadith

Tags: hadith, source-identification

Is there a hadith that says,
***the best of believers are those who observe the sun,moon and the stars for the remembrance of Allah***.

I remember hearing something like that and could someone please clarify this for me.

Comment: I have never heard such a hadith. But, it might be similar to the verse 3:190-191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Asalaam alaikum**

This Hadith is reported under *observing nature's wonders to remember Allah* in **al-sunan al-kubra** by imam bayhaqi.

Here is the narration;

> Ibn Abi Awfa reported: The Messenger of Allah ﷺ said, “Verily, among the best servants of Allah are those who observe the sun, the moon, the stars, and the shades for the remembrance of Allah.”

**Classification:**

This Hadith has been classed **Hasan li gayrihi** *(fair, due to external evidence)* by sheikh Albani.

**Reference**

Al-sunan al-kubra by imam bayhaqi

At-Targhib wa't-Tarhib by sheikh Albani

**Note** imam nasai also has a book titled by the same name Al-sunan al-kubra, not to be confused with.

May Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**Allah knows best**

Answer (score 0):

The hadith appears in Al-Mustadrak ([1/115](https://shamela.ws/book/2266/158)) with a Sahih Isnad, according to Al-Hakim, and Imam Dhahabi agrees.

Comment: Do you have an English version of the link that you have shared for that Hadith?, Jazaakahllah

Comment: English version should be within the post. Not everybody speaks Arabic.